# Store HDFS file contents in ArrayBuffer using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera, bigdata

I am trying to search for a particular keyword and put the entire row associated with the word in array buffer. I am using the below sample and trying to put all the **HHH** in array buffer.

**Sample**

```
PID|1|5897450M|58974650M|58977650M|CSTO^TES||19320722|F|||745 - 81 ST^^IAMI BEH^FL^341|||||||332165520
ORC||5033220|503320||||||20150202|||1689659096^HAM^MISH^^^^PI
OBR|1||64564|DF DEFAULT|||20150202|2015002||||||||16096^^^^^I|||||||||
HHH|1|NM|6690-2^^LN^0^^L||7|XE/UL|3.4-18||||F|||20150202| ^^L
HHH|9|NM|777-3^LOINC^LN^015172^PLATELETS^L||185|X10E3/UL|150-379||||F|||201202|TA   ^^L
HHH|10|NM|770-8^^LN^015107^^L||65|%|||||F|||20150202|TA   ^^L
HHH|11|NM|736-9^LOINC^LN^015123^^L||26|%|||||F|||20150202|TA   ^^L
HHH|12|NM|5905-5^LOINC^LN^015131^^L||8|%|||||F|||20150202|TA   ^^L
HHH|13|NM|713-8^LOINC^LN^015149^^L||1|%|||||F|||20150202|TA   ^^L
```

for achieving the goal i am writing this code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
object WordCount {
def main(args: Array[String])
{
    var arrybufobx =  ArrayBuffer[String]()
    val textfile = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/xxx/File")
    val word = textfile.filter(x => x.length >  0).map(_.split('|'))
    val obx = word.filter(_.contains("HHH"))
    val obxkeys = obx.map(a => s"${a(0)},${a(5)},${a(8)}").toString()
    arrybufobx += obxkeys
    arrybufobx.foreach { println }
}
}
```

but i am not able to see the contents of array buffer. I want to know how can i see my array buffer contents and is this the correct way to do this.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this as well . Make use of toBuffer Method to convert any collection into a  mutable collection .

I tried with below input

```
PID|1|5897450M
ORC||5033220
HHH|9|NM
HHH|1|NM
```

**Code:**

```
val myArr=Source.fromFile("C:\\Users\\hhh.txt").getLines().toArray;

val myFiltered= myArr.filter { x => x.length()>0 }.map { x => x.split("\\|") }

val finalData =myFiltered.filter { x => x.contains("HHH") }

var myMapped =finalData.map { x => x(0)+ ","+x(1)+","+ x(2) }

println(myMaped.toBuffer)
```

Output as per above code :

```
ArrayBuffer(HHH,9,NM, HHH,1,NM)
```

Comment: I tried the same code i am getting `error: value toBuffer is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
`

Comment: Source.fromFile i can use for hdfs files ? because my file is not in local.
because when i ran your code i am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/cloudera/xxx/File (No such file or directory)
`

Comment: Please help as i am stuck here